# Using property name and values from main view model in nested view model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view model like below. 
I would like to use the property name/values - `AllowOrgs` and `IsOrgOnly` in the nested view model - `EditAddressViewModel` too.
How to accomplish this objective?

My main view looks like this -

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=> m.AddressEditor,"AddAddress")
```

My main view model is like this -

```
public class AddressViewModel
{
    public EditAddressViewModel AddressEditor {get; set;}
    public bool AllowOrgs { get;set; }
    public bool IsOrgOnly { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Since you have view models, then `EditAddressViewModel` should just contain those properties, but you can pass the values using one of the the [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor``2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper{``0},System.Linq.Expressions.Expression{System.Func{``0,``1}},System.Object%29) of `EditorFor` that accepts `AdditionalViewData` - e.g. `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.AddressEditor, new { allowOrgs = Model.AllowOrgs })`

Comment: Can the `AdditonalViewData` be set on the fly or does it need to be part of a view bag in the parent view model?

Comment: `ViewBag` is not needed if `AllowOrgs` is part of the model. And in the template, access it using `bool AllowOrgs = ViewData["allowOrgs"];`

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how you can bind to the AllowOrgs property in AddressEditor?

If so then all you have to do is:
@Html.EditorFor(m=> m.AddressEditor.AllowOrgs,"AddAddress")

And Razor will take care of the rest.

If this not what you meant to ask please provide a little bit more information about what you are looking for.

Comment: No...that is not what I asked. I would like to utilize the values of `AllowOrgs` to be passed to the nested model. The `AddressEditor` does not have a `AllowOrgs` property.

Comment: Any reason why EditAddressViewModel couldn't inherit AddressViewModel? which would then only have the AllowOrgs and IsOrgOnly properties?